# How to extract all first objects for an object of array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I make an axios request like that :

```
async get() {
  await this.$axios.get(`my_api_url`)
    .then(response => {
       this.data = response.data;
     }).catch(() => { console.log('error') })
 },
```

It returns a response with these data:

```
{
    "Apple": [
        {
            "id": 26,
            "name": "Apple",
            "date_in": "2020-07-01"
        },
        {
            "id": 23,
            "name": "Apple",
            "date_in": "2020-06-01"
        }
    ],
    "Cherry": [
        {
            "id": 24,
            "name": "Cherry",
            "date_in": "2020-06-01"
        }
    ],
    "Banana": [
        {
            "id": 25,
            "name": "Banana",
            "date_in": "2020-06-01"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to be able to browse this object and keep only the first object in each table. Then put the selected objects in a new table.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: What is the code that you have tried so far. Where did you find difficulties in your code? Please post your efforts so far.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).map(([k,v])=>[k,v.slice(0,1)]))?  You mention a table, can't you just set the prop to only show a single element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like that?

```js
const src = {"Apple":[{"id":26,"name":"Apple","date_in":"2020-07-01"},{"id":23,"name":"Apple","date_in":"2020-06-01"}],"Cherry":[{"id":24,"name":"Cherry","date_in":"2020-06-01"}],"Banana":[{"id":25,"name":"Banana","date_in":"2020-06-01"}]},

      resultArr = Object.values(src).map(([o]) => o)

console.log(resultArr)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Or, like that?

```js
const src = {"Apple":[{"id":26,"name":"Apple","date_in":"2020-07-01"},{"id":23,"name":"Apple","date_in":"2020-06-01"}],"Cherry":[{"id":24,"name":"Cherry","date_in":"2020-06-01"}],"Banana":[{"id":25,"name":"Banana","date_in":"2020-06-01"}]},

      resultObj = Object.entries(src).reduce((r,[key,[o]]) => 
        (r[key] = o,r),{})


console.log(resultObj)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: The first proposal is what I'm looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

```js
function GetObjects(input){
    var output = [];
    for(let key in input){
        output.push(input[key][0]);
    }
    return output;
}
```

If I understand your question correctly

Comment: It works too, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the results like:

```
const data = {
    "Apple": [
        {
            "id": 26,
            "name": "Apple",
            "date_in": "2020-07-01"
        },
        {
            "id": 23,
            "name": "Apple",
            "date_in": "2020-06-01"
        }
    ],
    "Cherry": [
        {
            "id": 24,
            "name": "Cherry",
            "date_in": "2020-06-01"
        }
    ],
    "Banana": [
        {
            "id": 25,
            "name": "Banana",
            "date_in": "2020-06-01"
        }
    ]
}

const results = Object.keys(data).filter(item => data[item][0]).map(item => data[item][0]);
console.log(results);
```

Comment: it will also handle if your first object is not there.